# how will I download stackoverflow android dataset?

Tags: python, dataset

I need stackoverflow android dataset. i searched everywhere but did not find.
now i decided to scrape all android questions from stackoverflow. I have no knowlege of python. please give me direction or suggestion. a sample code will also be appreciated.
stack overflow android pages is almost 13 lac

I tried some online tools like import.io but that is trial version and don't know premium will be that much effective or not

Comment: Do you have experience in any other programming language?

Comment: For webscraping of unstructured data in general, if you know Python you can try beautifulsoup.  Question is too broad and is asking for a recommendation.  Stack Overflow is for specific technical questions after you have tried several different solutions and you can produce error messages from your efforts.  Try asking somewhere else that takes general & recommendation type of questions, like Quora.

Comment: yes i know java progamming... I only know basics of python

Answer (score 1):

Using APIs to get access to data - while easier than e.g. web scraping - still requires some understanding and knowledge of programming, although it doesn't need to be in Python.

If you have that knowledge, you can find what you need in the site's API documentation: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

If you don't, you'll need to either put in the time or hire someone to complete this task for you.